# API: keeping account balance positive (+knowing in advance the transaction fee)

Tags: json-rpc, transaction-fees, api, bitcoin-core-accounts

I'm using the [json API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list). I need to keep all the account balances positive: I call `getbalance` first, check if it has enough bitcoins to proceed, and then `move` or `sendfrom`.

This approach causes two problems.

Problem 1 is that this is not an atomic operation, so after the first `getbalance` the balance could actually be changed.

Problem 2 only happens with `sendfrom`: there might be a transaction fee, hence if the user sends his entire balance, he'll have a negative balance due to that.

Solution to Problem 2 would be to **know in advance the transaction fee**: I noticed (though I didn't try) I can *set* it with `settxfee`, but I found no call to *get* it, is there?

While I could implement some external lock mechanism to solve Problem 1, I'd rather use a bitcoind native method, though I get it does not exist, does it? **Hacking the `sendfrom` function to have it check the balance before sending** would be enough, I guess?

Comment: Are you making a bitcoin web application? How can the balance be lowered without you knowing? All money out goes through your API (code), doesn't it?

Comment: @Jori as I said, it's not an atomic operation.

Comment: How does that matter then? `bitcoind` will not send any coins out of an account if there are no coins in it. What is the purpose of checking the balance first?

Comment: The solution to problem 2 is just set the transaction fee yourself or go along with the default (which is best IMHO). See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees.